# trying to add Gmap.Net control to toolbox

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012, gmap.net

I have a WPF application targetting .Net framework 4.5 in Visual Studio 2012.

I have added references to GMap.NET.Core and System.Data.SQLLite.

In my App.config I have added

```
   <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true"> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/>
    </startup>
```

I open my Map.xaml page in VS, open the toolbox, right click, hit choose items.

Change tab to .NET Framework Components, Browse, select GMap.Net.WindowsForms.dll.  I see the entry for GMapControl pop up in the list, it's checked, I hit OK, I am then presented with the following:

[image]

I never end up seeing the control in my toolbox.  Help!

Edit: If I right click and hit `Show All`, I do see the control, it's just greyed out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bit late but just in case it helps anyone:

for WPF there is a different GMap.net to download: GMap.NET.WindowsPresentation

Once you have this:

- Add the GMap.NET.Core.dll and GMap.NET.WindowsPresentation.dll into your project file
- Add references to GMap.NET.Core.dll and GMap.NET.WindowsPresentation.dll
- Add in the toolbox by browsing to GMap.NET.WindowsPresentation.dll

If you get a message about

> "the assembly could not be loaded this assembly may have been
>   downloaded from the web"

then you need to change the properties of the two .dll files and unblock them.

I found this guide helpful, although it is for Windows Forms, not Windows Presentations:

http://www.websofia.com/2013/02/gmap-net-tutorial-maps-markers-and-polygons/

Comment: I don't see unblock button in my properties window.